# Silverlight ItemTemplate binding

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to set an ItemTimplate according to some property.
I've just create a markup, where I set ItemTemplate like this:

```
<controls:Panorama Title="Some Title" ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" ItemTemplate="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource ControlTemplateConverter}}">

    <controls:Panorama.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
    </controls:Panorama.Background>

</controls:Panorama>
```

And implement ControlTemplateConverter like this:

```
public class ControlTemplateConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder();
        sbTemp.Append("<DataTemplate ");
        sbTemp.Appen("xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' ");
        sbTemp.Append("xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' ");
        sbTemp.Append("<StackPanel>");
        sbTemp.Append("<TextBlock Text=\"News News\" />");
        sbTemp.Append("</StackPanel>");
        sbTemp.Append("</DataTemplate>");
        return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sbTemp.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I registered a converter:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:ControlTemplateConverter x:Key="ControlTemplateConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But when I set a breakpoint in ControlTemplateConverter.Convert it never stops in debug.
ItemSource loads everytime.
What's wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need a converter? Can you not declare your template in XAML?

Comment: I want to get dynamic itemtemplate binding. If some property equals 1, than i want to see one template and etc. Do you understand? I investigate, that when I set ItemTemplate like this ItemTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ControlTemplateConverter}}" (without Id), everyting works fine (converter works), but now I don't know how to pass a needed variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the binding fails to find the property `Id` in the same DataContext that the `Modules` property is found. Hence there is no call to the converter.  This is probably because `Id` is actually a property of each `Module` and somehow you imagine that the `ItemTemplate` binding gets resolved for each item.  It doesn't.  You have one template that gets applied to all items in the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: When I remove Id from Binding in Converter I receive the parent of Modules. How can I get a context of binding object or how can I bind a template according to the property of some object in other way?